# Visual Studio 2019 - How do I add a project to Azure DevOps Git?

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I've been trying to add a project to Azure Devops for hours now. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 and the "add to source control" only has a Git option and when I use that with my Azure remote URL it doesn't really work.

[image]
I've tried everything I can think of...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Visual Studio 2019 - How do I add a project to Azure DevOps Git?

There is no standard process to realize it, as long as it can be finally realized, Just as the word, all roads lead to Rome.

I will simply share some steps I usually use to achieve it, hope give you any help.

**1.** Create a new project in the Azure Devops reppo and version control select Git:

[image]

**2.** Initialize the repo and add the Visual Studio as gitignore type:

[image]

**3.** Open the Visual Studio and open the team explorer, clone the repo:

[image]

**4.** Add a new project to the repo, select the repo folder in local:

[image]

There is [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0yJYKMaL4I) about it, you can refer it for some more details.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Kind of crazy how MS makes things worse after each release...